# Struts 2 mapping are not working with Struts 2.3.15 lib

Tags: java, xml, struts2, annotations

I have created struts 2(Struts version 2.2) application with annotations.It does not exist a **`struts.xml`** file and all the things are working properly.

Now I need to update the struts version to 2.3.15. and Struts mappings are not working after version updation. I'm using struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.15.jar.

My **`web.xml`** here

```
web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>test</display-name>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mypackages</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Any new configurations for annotations with this struts version?

Comment: do you get any error in your console when starting the application?

Comment: There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name "actionname"